# How to apply Prewitt Edge Detection algorithm on a given image?

Tags: edge-detection

I am trying to figure out the answer to the following question:
[image]

As I understand it, I am supposed to apply the algorithm only on this part of the image

```
[2,5,6]
[4,2,7]
[1,3,5]
```

My question is how to apply the two gradients for x and y respectively on this part of the image? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to answer my question after doing more research. The key is to slide the 3x3 kernel and perform Gx and Gy (gradient for the x and y directions) and calculate the output image values. For example, to calculate the output image top left value -

```
[x - -]
[- - -]
[- - -]
```

we have to calculate both gradients (x and y)->

Gx

```
[-1 0 1]
[-1 0 1]
[-1 0 1]
```

we take the first chunk of the original image (e.g. sliding the kernel over the top values of the input image)

```
[1 2 4]
[5 2 5]
[5 4 2]
```

Gx = 4+5+2 - 1-5-5 = 0

Gy = 5+4+2 - 1-2-4 = 4
We take the absolute values of both and sum them so |4| + |0| = 4

And this is the first top value of the output image.

```
[4 - -]
[- - -]
[- - -]
```

The same way we calculate the rest. I hope that will help anyone else facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

final answer is

```
[0 0 0 0 0]
[0 4 9.2 6.08 0]
[0 7.07 11.7 1.41 0]
[0 3.16 7.07 7.61 0]
[0 0 0 0 0]
```